# How to print list as separarte strings in django template

Tags: python, django

I want to print list as a separate strings in html
For example: `['one','two','three']`

output- one,two,three

for loop didn't work it prints one letter per line instead one item

I tried slugify but it ads dashes

```
{{item.notes|slugify}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#join) each element of the list with a comma, assuming your list is stored in `value`, use the following:

```
{{ value|join:"," }}
```

The output will be:

```
one,two,three
```

Comment: I tried above things and now it's like adding comma after every single letter. I am trying to access a list from database into my template as a string... please help.. is there any other way to solve this??

Comment: @GouriB, how are you passing that list in the `context` from your view? The answer I gave you should work. if you are using `context = {'value': ['one','two','three']}`

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you so much for the help :)